# Is using a timestamp as a hash key on a GSI in DynamoDB a good approach

Tags: indexing, amazon-dynamodb

I have a large (2B + records) DynamoDB table.
I want to implement a distributed locking process by adding a new field, 'index_due_at' when an item is created or updated.  After the create/update, I will do some further processing on the item and then remove the 'index_due_at' field.

I'd like to create a sweeper job which will periodically extract any records with an outstanding 'index_due_at' field (on the assumption that something about the above process failed) to give those records further treatment. I would anticipate at most 100s of records in this state at any one time, more likely 10s.

To optimise the performance of the sweeper, I want to create a GSI including the new field (and project the key data into it).

It seems that using a timestamp (in millis) as the GSI HASH key ought to give a good distribution. And I don't need to query on this field's value, just on its presence.  Can anyone identify any drawbacks in this approach and if so, suggest an alternative?

Issues I can anticipate include:
* Non-uniqueness in timestamps at milli level.
* Possible hash key problems with numeric values?
* Possible hash key problems with numeric values that don't vary much in the most significant digits.

Comment: If you need distributed locking, you should consider DynamoDBLockClient before trying to implement it yourself. https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-lock-client

Comment: GSI does not enforce uniqueness. So you can have multiple items with same GSI hash key. No problem of that if your `Non-uniqueness in timestamps at milli level` means that

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to DynamoDBLockClient. It's probably a little heavy for what we're trying to achieve here but it's a good tool to know about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is less of a problem than you might be thinking. GSI hash keys don't actually have to be unique, so you're fine on than front.

You probably already know this, but your GSI will only contain items with GSI keys, so your GSI should be pretty small (100s of items).

One thought I have is that the `index_due_at` might actually be better as a GSI sort key rather than hash key. Data is sorted within a partition by sort key. So you could have a GSI hash key of `index_due_at_flag` which would be `Y` if present, then a sort key of `index_due_at`. This would mean all your data would be sorted naturally, so you could process it in date order.

That said, you are probably never going to Query this GSI, so I suspect your choice of keys hardly matters at all. Presumably you will just do a Scan, get all the items and try and process them all. In which case you would never even use the keys. Just having a key attribute present would put the item in the GSI.

Another thought is that you need to handle the fact GSIs are not perfectly synchronous with the base table. Its possible (admittedly unlikely) that an item in your GSI has actually just been processed. Therefore if your sweeper script picks up an item from the GSI, you should handle the fact its possible its already been updated in the base table (e.g. by checking the base table item before attempting to process it).

Good luck with it. I answered because I liked your bio! Hope staying on the right side of barrel shaped is working out :)

Comment: Thanks for addressing the specific questions.  It has been pointed out to me that if Bad Things Happen, we could actually end up with c/a 100K items in the GSI but to your point, we'd still scan (with pagination) to recover them all. Thanks also for the reminder to update my profile; new company, new role, same barrel distortion issues.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a perfect scenario for using [DynamoDB Sparse Index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-general-sparse-indexes.html)
Use the 'index_due_at' as sort key in GSI, and only the items you are interested will be in the index, greatly reducing the space needed and the performance.